# Clickable Element under Overlay - HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

so I am currently working on a web-app with a nav-bar on the bottom. I decided to have a linear-gradient overlay above the underlying elements in order to make the menu more visible.
[You can see in this screenshot what I mean, I think.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjoxj.png)
Now I faced the problem that when an item I want to be clickable is just below that, one can obviously not click that. I can't change the z-index since that would defeat the whole purpose of the overlay.

The Overlay is just a background applied to the menu div, which is located at the very bottom in the dom.

Its CSS:

```
div{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5em 0 1em 0;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--opaque-main-background), var(--main-background));
  }
```

All the other elements, including those I want to be clickable have no particular positioning. It's a vue app, so if you need any more information I forgot, here is a [live demo](https://luebz-liefert.de/dev/). You may have to resize the window for the issue to kick in

Is there any basic/simple solution to this problem I am just not seeing right now?

Comment: Why not just add some more vertical spacing at the bottom of the page content at the same height as your navbar, so that the user simply just scrolls down further to be able to click the (last) elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. here is a solution.

- add `pointer-event:none` to this menu div above in css.
- then to each span add a `pointer-event: auto` like this:

  span[data-v-4fb6fd22] {
      position: relative;
      pointer-events: auto;
  }

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointer-events here. Just add `pointer-events:none` to your css for `div`

```
div{
  pointer-events:none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5em 0 1em 0;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--opaque-main-background), var(--main-background));
}
```

Hope it helps.